# OR TOOLS decision variable as for-loop argument

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, or-tools, cp-sat

I am trying to run my CP model after making changes to some variables, thanks to this [link](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/docs/model.md#python-code).

I want to use a constant decision variable as an argument my for loop.

example:

```
model = cp_model.Cpmodel()

max_val = model.NewConstant(val)      # 'val' is a normal python variable

for i in range(max_val):
   <do something>
```

I am aware that it is not possible from the availabe OR TOOLS function but is there any way round to this? I want to try different `max_val` values and run my Model multiple times by copying it and chaning the `val` variable. Any ideas? It will be very helpful.

thanks :)

Comment: Hi @LaurentPerron , do you have any advise on this?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your code:

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

def run_model(arg_val):
      print(f'run {arg_val}')
      model = cp_model.CpModel()
      x = [model.NewIntVar(0, 5, 'var_x') for _ in range(arg_val)]
      y = model.NewIntVar(0, 10, 'var_y')

      for i in range(arg_val):
            model.Add(x[i] + y <= 13)

      solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
      solver.parameters.num_workers = 1
      print(solver.StatusName(solver.Solve(model)))



def main():    
     run_model(5)     # here there is no solution for MY model
     run_model(6)     # here there is an OPTIMAL solution

main()
```

and ran it

```
run 5
OPTIMAL
run 6
OPTIMAL
```

Comment: thanks for the edit. The problem I am facing is, let's say if I have a 'NO SOLUTION' for an argument but have OPTIMAL SOLUTION for the next input. When I call the function with these two arguments consecutively, the solver also gives 'NO SOLUTION' for the next argument value which definitely has an OPTIMAL SOLUTION. I am sure my model is correct. I get OPTIMAL SOLUTION for the correct input. What can be the issue? Is this the solver's behavior that after finding a NO SOLUTION every next call back will be a NO SOLUTION? Please help

Comment: Solve is stateless. So if you recreate the model and the solver, spill over does not happen.

Comment: Okay, quick question, how to do that? I am sorry but I do not know what stateless means. any minor changes I have to make to avoid spill over?

Comment: I do not think this is a bug of CP-SAT. Perhaps a property of your model that every value after a failing one is also failing.

Comment: I verified this and you are right,  some constraints are failing and not finding the solution and that is affecting the forthcoming iteration of the model. Is there any way I can delete the model when it fails to find a solution or remove the state of the model for the next iteration?

Comment: There are not states. When you recreate the model and the solver, it inherits nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255197/discussion-between-ken-adams-and-laurent-perron).